# Swift Keep variable after @IBAction button pressed

Tags: swift

I am working on the "tip calculator" and am running into a problem. Once I put in the info into the UITextField and run the app it calculates correctly. Then I go to adjust the tip slider value or number of people to another value, hit calculate again and my variable from tabBill is wiped out along with all the other values. If i comment out the currency formatter it will do what i want it to. How can I get the variable to hold its value so I can make an adjustment to one field and then run it again while keeping the currency format? Please be super specific as I am so new to a lot of this terminology.

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("refresh requested")

        let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle

        let tabBill = (billAmountTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
        billAmountTextField.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tabBill)
        billAmountTextField.text != "\(tabBill)"

        peoplePaying = (numberOfPeoplePaying.text as NSString).doubleValue

        tipTotal = tabBill * tipPercent

        tipPerPerson = Double(tipTotal) / Double(peoplePaying)
        tipPerPersonAmount.text = "\(tipPerPerson)"
        tipPerPersonAmount.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipPerPerson)

        totalPerPersonDue = (tabBill + tipTotal) / peoplePaying
        totalPerPerson.text = "\(totalPerPersonDue)"
        totalPerPerson.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(totalPerPersonDue)

        tipTotalAmount.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipTotal)
        totalBillWithTip = Double(tabBill)+Double(tipTotal)

        totalBillAmountWithTip.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(totalBillWithTip)

        //console output
        println("tabBill:\(tabBill)", "sliderValue:\(sliderValue)", "tipPercent:\(tipPercent)", "tipTotal:\(tipTotal)", "tipPerPerson:\(tipPerPerson)", "peoplePaying:\(peoplePaying)", "totalPerPersonDue:\(totalPerPersonDue)", "totalBillWithTip:\(totalBillWithTip)")
}
```

Comment: If you declare your variable outside the method, it will keep its value for as long as your view controller is around. If a variable needs to persist for longer time (say, if you wish the value to survive closing of your application) use `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I do not need to keep it after the app closes, however I am assuming that you mean to declare the variable in the viewController .swift and I declared it at the very top of the page, just under the UIKit. Same thing. I am sorry these are such noob questions. I kind of assumed that but i still cannot get what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you run the app you have a double in the text field (lets say 10.00) so the conversion work fine, but then you transform this double into a currency and save into the textfield (now its value is $10.00), this new text field cannot be converted to a double the way you did at the first time, try to run the value of the text field trough this function:

```
func currencyStringAsDouble(currencyString: String) -> Double {
    let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    let cleanedString = currencyString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.currencySymbol, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator, withString: "")
    let currencyDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue
    return currencyDouble;
}
```

This function will convert your currency string back to doulbe again, in your case you would do:

```
let tabBill = currencyStringAsDouble(billAmountTextField.text)
```

So your final code will look like this:

@IBAction func calculateButtonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("refresh requested")

```
    let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle

    //***Only line that change***//
    let tabBill = currencyStringAsDouble(billAmountTextField.text)

    billAmountTextField.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tabBill)
    billAmountTextField.text != "\(tabBill)"

    peoplePaying = (numberOfPeoplePaying.text as NSString).doubleValue

    tipTotal = tabBill * tipPercent

    tipPerPerson = Double(tipTotal) / Double(peoplePaying)
    tipPerPersonAmount.text = "\(tipPerPerson)"
    tipPerPersonAmount.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipPerPerson)

    totalPerPersonDue = (tabBill + tipTotal) / peoplePaying
    totalPerPerson.text = "\(totalPerPersonDue)"
    totalPerPerson.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(totalPerPersonDue)

    tipTotalAmount.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipTotal)
    totalBillWithTip = Double(tabBill)+Double(tipTotal)

    totalBillAmountWithTip.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(totalBillWithTip)

    //console output
    println("tabBill:\(tabBill)", "sliderValue:\(sliderValue)", "tipPercent:\(tipPercent)", "tipTotal:\(tipTotal)", "tipPerPerson:\(tipPerPerson)", "peoplePaying:\(peoplePaying)", "totalPerPersonDue:\(totalPerPersonDue)", "totalBillWithTip:\(totalBillWithTip)")
}

//Add new function to convert currency to double
 func currencyStringAsDouble(currencyString: String) -> Double {
        let cleanedString = currencyString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.currencySymbol, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator, withString: "")
        let currencyDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue
        return currencyDouble;
}
```

Comment: I totally get your explanation, however the code you are suggesting to add makes no sense. I am sorry these are such noob questions. Is there any way to just simply convert that string back to a double? If not, I am not ever sure that I understand where to put this code, or what you mean by running the value of the "text field" through the above function. What text field??? Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean make no sense? It take a string like $4.00 and return 4.00 and that is what you need

Comment: I am going to mess around with it more. That is what I was kind of trying to say, I now understand the logic in the code why it will not work, but I have not quite figured out the code its self. I will keep working on it and let you know when I get it figured out. Thank for your help so far and your time.

Comment: In you code add this line println("The value I am trying to convert to double is \(billAmountTextField.text)") after println("refresh requested") and let us know what it say, it my be easy to show you what I mean this way

Comment: This was the output to my console.
The value I am trying to convert to double is $22.00
refresh requested

Comment: See that is the problem you are having you cannot convert $22.00 to double, the function I gave to you get the $22.00 and return 22.00, that can be converted to double.

Comment: This is what is confusing, I really feel like I am not getting something. I added the code like you showed, and keep getting errors. Here are a few:
Use of unresolved identifier 'currencyFormatter' (i then added a global variable 'currencyFormatter' and then got the following)

'String' does not have a member named currencySymbol
use of unresolved identifier 'text'
I understand int to string back to int, the logic. I do not get your function. I am sorry if I sound dense, but I have literally been learning Swift for a month, and programming in general for 6 months.

Comment: Sorry I miss that, let currencyFormatter is a NSNumberFormatter, I added in the answer

Comment: I fixed the issue with an if statement in the button press. Thanks for your help.

if (billAmountTextField.text == (tabBillString)) {
            tabBillString = tabBillString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(tabBillString, withString: " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
            billAmountTextField.text = "\(tabBillDouble)"